# Renaming Model in branch cause all other branch to fail

Tags: django, git, django-models

I got a Model called Cars.

```
Master branch: Cars    
Branch feature/search: Cars    
Branch feature/showcar: Cars
```

I renamed the Cars model to Car in branch, in order to make it work, I makemigrates and migrate it on feature/search branch now it becomes

```
Master branch: Cars
Branch feature/search: **Car**
Branch feature/showcar: Cars
```

It cause master and feature/showcar branch error, they couldn't find a model Cars in the database. 
And I cause my team a lot of problem.

What could prevent this from happening?
I hope this is clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After you've changed database description and migrated your database the descriptions in other branches are not compatible with `master` branch. There are few ways to work with this.

1. Synchronize database descriptions in all branches by merging `master` into all branches. Push all branches to the central repository and notify all developers in your team to update and migrate.
2. Have database description in `master` to be different from other branches. Migrate when switching from `master` to a different branch and migrate again when switching to `master`.

3a. Have different databases for every branch. Change `settings.py` when switching branches.

3b. Use many different worktrees for branches, so every branch has its own database description and every worktree its own `settings.py`.